# jhipster-docker : spring-boot does not terminate with control C

Tags: docker, spring-boot, jhipster

I can't seem to stop spring-boot after I generate and run a project using jdubois/jhipster-docker.   When I press control C, it tries to stop but hangs and requires me to restart the entire docker-machine.

What's the proper way to stop a the jhipster application ?

```
I'm using OS X 10.11.2.
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
docker-machine version 0.5.4, build 6643d0e
latest version of jdubois/jhipster-docker
```

Here's the docker run command I'm running:

```
$ docker run -u jhipster -w /home/jhipster/app -p 8080:8080 -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t jdubois/jhipster-docker
```

Then I use the following to "connect" to the container:

```
$ docker exec -it<container-id> bash
```

Once I'm in the container, I generate an app and use the defaults for all questions.

```
jhipster@926b84ce422c:~/app$ yo jhipster testapp

.... take defaults for all questions ....
.... lots of output from generator here.... 

jhipster@926b84ce422c:~/app$ mvn
```

The app starts up as expected.  Here's the last bit of the output :

```
2016-01-13 14:52:56.244 DEBUG 347 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 17 ms
2016-01-13 14:52:59.714  INFO 347 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.myapp.Application          : Started Application in 27.602 seconds (JVM running for 28.696)
2016-01-13 14:52:59.716  INFO 347 --- [  restartedMain] com.mycompany.myapp.Application          : Access URLs:
----------------------------------------------------------
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8080
    External:   http://172.17.0.2:8080
----------------------------------------------------------
```

At this point I press control C and I expect spring-boot to stop but it shows the following output and then hangs. At this point I can't stop the container.  I have to restart the entire docker-machine.

```
^C2016-01-13 14:53:10.019  INFO 347 --- [      Thread-10] c.m.myapp.config.CacheConfiguration      : Remove Cache Manager metrics
2016-01-13 14:53:10.041  INFO 347 --- [      Thread-10] c.m.myapp.config.CacheConfiguration      : Closing Cache Manager
```

Comment: JAVA applications hanging/becoming defunct may be due to a Kernel bug that's affecting boot2docker 1.9.1 (and various versions of ubuntu); see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180#issuecomment-166186061

Answer (score 0):

If you have mvn, npm and java installed on your docker host you could add volumes to your docker run commmand and start the app outside the docker container which enables you to stop the app with ctrl + c

So create the app from within your docker container and then exit out of the container. Now goto your directory you mapped to the hipster docker container and run

```
mvn
```

Below are the steps you have taken but I changed them a little

```
$ docker run -u jhipster -v ~/jhipster:/home/jhipster/app:rw -v ~/.m2:/home/jhipster/.m2:rw -w /home/jhipster/app -p 8080:8080 -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t jdubois/jhipster-docker
$ docker exec -it<container-id> bash
jhipster@926b84ce422c:~/app$ yo jhipster testapp

.... take defaults for all questions ....
.... lots of output from generator here.... 

jhipster@926b84ce422c:~/app$ exit
$ cd ~/jhipster
$ mvn
```